# I do not know how to diagram this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

How would I diagram

> Unless we share the food, many of us will go home without any food.

Comment: There is no standard method of diagramming English sentences. Fifty years ago Reed-Kellogg was standard in the US, but since then tree-, arrow- and bracket-based schemes have mostly displaced R-K; and every grammatical theory has its own method of disposing and labeling nodes.

Comment: Go ahead and add how you think it should be diagrammed to your question.